# Index file can not run direct when enter URL in my java website?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, struts2

I am working on a Java project on a webserver. Uploading the `.war` file goes fine. When I navigate to the site name, for example `www.example.com`, the website gives me an error; but entering `www.example.com/index.jsp` works fine. I want the second request to be equivalent to the first.

Comment: This is a config parameter in your webserver.

Comment: This will depend on your web server. You need to set `index.jsp` as the default page.

Comment: I already set index.jsp as default page but it is not working...

Answer (score 0):

In web.xml you need to specify the following

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

And index.jsp must placed in root context folder